# Doctors, Patients and Contact information for both

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `DOCTORS` and `PATIENTS`. I want both the doctors and the patients to have contact information (such as telephone numbers, addresses and so on) that aren't fixed. For example we can add multiple phones to either a doctor or a patient.

I thought about creating a separate table e.g. `PHONES` with fields `phoneID`, the phone number and a foreign key that points to a contact, such as below:

**PHONES**

```
phoneID [pk]
number
contactID [fk]
```

**DOCTORS**

```
docID [pk]
fname
sname
specialization
.
.
.
```

**PATIENTS**

```
patID [pk]
fname
sname
.
.
.
```

The first problem comes from the fact that the `patID` and the `docID` might (and will eventually) have the same value. So relating a phone to one and only one person becomes more difficult.

So far I've thought three possible solutions:

1. Have custom format primary keys for the doctors and patients. For example doctors could have ids in the form of "d00001", "d00002" and so on, and patients ids like "p00001", "p00002". My concern is this could complicate things unnecessarily.
2. Another solution would be to keep both doctors and patients in one table, and define if they are a doctor or a patient by using another field.
3. Create separate `PHONE` tables for doctors and patients, but that's even more clumsy.

Somehow I think both approaches are not the best. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a `PERSON`-table. This is `1:1` related to your doctors and patients (and later maybe to employees, suppliers, institutions, whatever). Let the contacts be related to this person-table.

Application code can model this with inheritance quite easily...

Within your person-table you keep some general information like `DisplayName` and `PersonType` (reference to a person-type-table with entries like `Doctor`, `Patient` and ...).

Keep this table slim...

If you have to choose out of your own ideas, I'd prefer the second. Keep them in one table and mark them with a type column. Avoid *speaking keys*...

Comment: Thanks, this answer definitely solves the problem presented and helps extend my web application, as the People table could be useful to keep not only display names but also display pictures. I'm also considering what "dbenham" said below though as it's necessary that children patients for example will want to share their parents phone numbers and addresses. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Paradoxo44 I'm glad, that you like it! You might want to read my comment to dbenham's answer...

Comment: Is something like this what you propose?
[![model.jpg](https://s11.postimg.org/iidjcdp43/model.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/ux0bcpgm7/)

Comment: @Paradoxo44 Yes, quite like this... The relation between `tblPersons` and the specialisations `tblDoctors` and `tblPatients` should be `1:1`, because a doctor **is** this person and a patient **is** this person. One person might be a doctor **and** a patient. Think of this like a person's role...

Comment: In this case refID in tblPersons could refer to two people with the same ID (e.g. docID = 5, and patID = 5) and I would have to make the check from inside my app code. I guess that is why I need the PersonType declared in the table Persons. Or I have missed something.

Comment: @Paradoxo44, Sorry, I looked at it not carefully enough... I thought this exactly the other way round: There is one person table. Every natural or jurstic entity is a "person". The doctor's table gets a PersonID and the patient's table gets a PersonID. This can be seen as *This person has a Doctor role* or *This person has a Patient role*...

Comment: Stuck in a 'minor' problem that wouldn't be there if I decided to have fixed phone numbers and addresses, but then it wouldn't be a challange. 
And I haven't even gotten to the doctor availability / bookings part yet! Fun times.

Comment: @Paradoxo44 Well, challenges are there to be solved :-) You must distinguish between things which are specific to a role (only a doctor has availability / bookings and only a patient has diagnosis or treatment) and such data valid *everywhere*: addresses and phone numbers, Displayname and -picture... But  - admitably -  sometimes the *not-so-clean-and-perfect* design is better, faster, lighter and - uhm - good enough... This depends on the use cases you want to modell.

Comment: [![model.jpg](https://s18.postimg.org/n8y7fmwvd/model.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/w3z1q5lnp/)

Came up with this.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about the relationships wrong.

There is a many to many relationship between person and phone number.

A single person can have many different phone numbers (home, work, mobile, etc.)

A single phone number can be associated with many people (husband, wife, children, co-worker, ...)

I don't see why you need a primary entity with phone number as a primary or alternate key.

I would use 5 tables:

```
Doctor PK=DoctorID

Patient PK=PatientID

PhoneType PK=PhoneTypeCode

DoctorPhone PK=DoctorID,PhoneTypeCode,PhoneNum  
  FK1=Doctor.DoctorID  
  FK2=PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode

PatientPhone PK=PatientID,PhoneTypeCode,PhoneNum
  FK1=Patient.PatientID
  FK2=PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode
```

You might consider having distinct DoctorPhoneType and PatientPhoneType tables, given that the phone roles are likely to be different between the two classes of people.

Comment: You are very right, the patients might include family and so the phones and addresses will be shared. I began designing my DB thinking that I will absolutely have to avoid using duplicate tables for the same things: phones and addresses. But you make a fair point. Thanks for your input!

Comment: To be honest, I think this design goes to far... Shared addresses or contact infos get you in deepest troubles, if - for example - the eldest child gets his own phone number. Changing a shared number, spreads this to everyone. So you'd have to define a number's owner, and introduce a bunch of extra logic. Much better for me is an *inheritance cascade*: If the child has no phone number, we look at the relations and see, if the closes upper relative has got a phone. We do this until we find a families phone number. If father and mother have their own phone numbers, we'll find one of them...

Comment: @Shnugo - What shared contact info? Each patient or doctor has his/her own set of phone numbers that is not shared.

Comment: Your *A single phone number can be associated with many people* makes me think, that your `m:n` approach would bind one info to many people. One address to a whole family, one phone number to a mother and her children... But if you change this (divorce, father changes flat, *Oh, I have a new address!*) everybody would get this new address. This **can** be a good approach, but in normal *doctor-patient* software this is highly sophisticated and far beyond the worker's abilities to mainain... Don't you think so?

Comment: @Shnugo - It still seems we are talking cross purposes. Yes, I stated that a single phone number can apply to many people, and my model allows the same number to be assigned to any number of people. But I haven't modeled a phone number as a primary entity. In my model, the phone numbers of each patient must be maintained independently. Changing the father's phone number has no impact on anyone else in the family. Look at my model again. Note that PhoneTypeCode represents something like "Home", "Work", etc. *not* a phone number.

Comment: @dbenham OK, I see... But in this case I'd prefer my suggested `Person` table as a meta table. Otherwise you would have to add new tables if you add new contact types. Correct? I'm working in medical software too. Our customers would just not have the time to maintain complex related/shared/whatever contacts or addresses. They have to fill in a new person within a few seconds... They have to edit an address out of a phone call. And - in most cases - they won't ever contact these people by phone or snail mail. If this is needed, they rather invest some minutes to search for the number...